# How to route to a different screen after a state change?

Tags: flutter

I'm using flutter_redux and google_sign_in and I want to route from the Login page to a different page after logging in.

I am handling the API call to Google using middleware that dispatches a `LoggedInSuccessfully` action. I know I can use `Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/routeName")` for the actual routing, but I am new to both Flutter and Redux and my problem is that I just don't know *where* to call this.

The code below is for the `GoogleAuthButtonContainer`, which is my guess as to where the routing should be. The `GoogleAuthButton` is just a plain widget with the actual button and layout.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new StoreConnector<AppState, _ViewModel>(
      converter: _ViewModel.fromStore,
      builder: (BuildContext context, _ViewModel vm) {
        return new GoogleAuthButton(
          buttonText: vm.buttonText,
          onPressedCallback: vm.onPressedCallback,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class _ViewModel {
  final String buttonText;
  final Function onPressedCallback;

  _ViewModel({this.onPressedCallback, this.buttonText});

  static _ViewModel fromStore(Store<AppState> store) {
    return new _ViewModel(
        buttonText:
        store.state.currentUser != null ? 'Log Out' : 'Log in with Google',
        onPressedCallback: () {
          if (store.state.currentUser != null) {
            store.dispatch(new LogOut());
          } else {
            store.dispatch(new LogIn());
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Rather than handling the login via an Action, you may want to make it more synchronous. This will help you respond to any errors on the login (by keeping the user on the login page and present an error) and it may make it easy to do the navigation once your auth callback completes successfully. So instead of calling `store.dispatch(new LogIn());` you can call a function `_login()` which then has the same code that is currently in your middleware.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve this by 3 different ways:

- Call the navigator directly (without using the ViewModel), but this is not a clean solution.
- Set the `navigatorKey` and use it in a `Middleware` as described [here](https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_architecture_samples/issues/26#issuecomment-371099897)
- And another solution is what I've explained [here](https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_architecture_samples/issues/26#issuecomment-374530400) which is passing the `Navigator` to the `Action` class and use it in the `Middleware`

So to sum up, you probably want to use a `Middleware` to do the navigation.

Comment: Wow, thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Great to hear!!

Comment: @XaviRigau can you please give some example of middleware based approach apart from the link which you have given

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found any other examples using the same approach, sorry @WitVault